# Reading user input into a list through a class member

Tags: c#, list, class

I'm struggling to find an answer to my problem anywhere so I don't expect this to be a duplicate, my bad if it is!

I have been set a task using classes, this is the first time I have been using classes & lists so forgive my ignorance.

I want to store the data that has been read into one of my class members (I must use the class members throughout the task)  through the user input and add this to the list that I have created. I've tried numerous way but now I'm out of ideas. The program is letting me enter the first value (the make) but the compiler then throws an error saying:

"An unhanded exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"
"Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

```
  private static void AddCar(Vechicle _Motor)
  {
      int number = 1;
      Console.Clear();
      List<Vechicle> MotorDeats = new List<Vechicle>();
      Console.Write("/////////////////////ADDING CAR DETAILS\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
      Console.Write("\n\nEnter Make: ");
      _Motor.Make = Console.ReadLine();
      MotorDeats[number].Add(_Motor.Make);
      Console.Write("\n\nEnter Model: ");
      _Motor.Model = Console.ReadLine();
      MotorDeats[number].Add(_Motor.Model);
      Console.Write("\n\nEnter Year: ");
      _Motor.Year = Console.ReadLine();
      MotorDeats[number].Add(_Motor.Year);

      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", MotorDeats.Select(MotorDeat => MotorDeats.ToString())));
      Console.ReadKey();


  }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Vechicle v = new Vechicle();
v.Make = 'Ford';
v.Year = 1990;
v.Model = 'Sedan'
MotorDeats.Add(v);
```

You don't index the list in order to add an item. It automatically adds it to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to pass your list to `AddCar` because you lose your `MotorDeats`

```
private static void AddCar(List<Vehicle> vehicles)
{

      Console.Clear();
      Console.Write("/////////////////////ADDING CAR DETAILS\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
      var v = new Vehicle();
      Console.Write("\n\nEnter Make: ");
      v.Make = Console.ReadLine();

      Console.Write("\n\nEnter Model: ");
      v.Model = Console.ReadLine();

      Console.Write("\n\nEnter Year: ");
      v.Year = Console.ReadLine();

      vehicles.Add(v);
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", vehicles.Select(_ => _.ToString())));
      Console.ReadKey();


}
```

This way you can collect your cars. Or you can create loop like this

```
while (str != "n")  
{


    // your code
     Console.Write("Add another Car? (Y/N)");
     string result = Console.ReadLine();
     if (result.ToLower() == "n")
        str = "n";
}
```

This will allow you to put multiple vehicles